# Git status showing something in .gitignore

Tags: git, status

I have a .gitignore with:

```
config.ini
thingy.csv
```

git status shows:

```
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    modified:   .gitignore
    modified:   thingy.csv
```

Any idea why it's ignoring the .ini and not the .csv?

Comment: Was the ini committed before? I believe git does not ignore already committed files, which is why your .csv is still tracked

Comment: I fixed the second thingy.csv!

Answer (score 0):

Thingy.csv was committed to git. I removed it and .gitignore did the right thing.